# How do I edit the .plist for a React Native Project when it is auto-generated as part of the bundling process?

Tags: xcode, react-native, plist

I am building a React Native application that allows arbitrary loads of non https websites. Basically I want to load a webview that uses an http site.

However non-http requests are disabled by default when the project is bundled. I have opened the .plist and know how to alter it to allow loading of non-http sites, however in order to run the app in the simulator on my Mac it needs to re-bundle it again and it replaces all custom .plist keys.

I havent included any code here as it isn't necessary here. It is altering the default build process that I am interested in.

I've had harsh feedback from asking question before so have spent considerable time reading the documentation with no avail.

Thanks for your help and please have mercy.

Comment: Which `.plist` are you referring to? For me only the `info.plist` under `[my-project]/ios/build` gets rewritten. The one from `[my-project]/ios/[project-name]` does not. I am putting the domains I have to make calls to and are not `https` in there, not in the `.plist` under `build`.

Comment: Thank you Peter - I was trying to allow arbitrary loads from my info.plist. Is this not the best thing to do? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved a similar problem that may work for you. I think you can use `NSExceptionDomains` to set the exception case.

```html
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>localhost</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>rap2api.taobao.org</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

You can check my post here: [Can't fetch or make XHR request to http URL in React Native (but https and http://localhost work fine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48071550/cant-fetch-or-make-xhr-request-to-http-url-in-react-native-but-https-and-http/48071751#48071751)