# Can't fetch or make XHR request to http URL in React Native (but https and http://localhost work fine)

Tags: react-native

I tried to make a request to the remote server in React Native, but always get `TypeError: Network request failed`; I tried different URL, and found that if I make a request to some http URL like `http://rap2api.taobao.org/app/mock/3008/GET/api/creations`, it always failed;
if I make a request to some https URL like `https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json`, it works;
if I make a request to a http localhost URL like `http://localhost:3002/list`, it also works.

```js
componentDidMount() {
  console.log("_fetchData");
  this._fetchData()
}
_fetchData = () => {
      fetch('http://rap2api.taobao.org/app/mock/3008/GET/api/creations')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
          console.log('responseJson',responseJson)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    
}
```

I checked many references online and guess it's something about the setting in Info.plist doc. I tried to do some modification like:

```html
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>localhost</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>rap2api.taobao.org</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

or

```html
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```

However, neither of them works, I still get the same error when making requesting to http URL. I am sure the API is fine since I tried it on a web application and get the response successfully. What's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html:

> By default, iOS will block any request that's not encrypted using SSL. If you need to fetch from a cleartext URL (one that begins with http) you will first need to add an App Transport Security exception. If you know ahead of time what domains you will need access to, it is more secure to add exceptions just for those domains; if the domains are not known until runtime you can disable ATS completely. Note however that from January 2017, Apple's App Store review will require reasonable justification for disabling ATS. See Apple's documentation for more information.

and from https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33

> Starting in iOS 10.0 and later and in macOS 10.12 and later, the following subkeys are supported:
>   NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia
>   NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent
>   NSRequiresCertificateTransparency
>   NSAllowsLocalNetworking
>   **Note: There are two “allows arbitrary loads” keys and they employ different naming patterns. Take care to use …ForMedia and …InWebContent correctly.**

You might try explicitly setting NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia and NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent.

Also be sure to clean and rebuild your project in Xcode so that your updated plist settings are included in your package.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. I tried to set NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia and NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent, but it still didn't tackle the error. I think your answer is right but I guess info.plist may not take effect. I don't know how can I do the "clean and rebuild your project in Xcode" in react native, I tried to open the ios folder of the react native project in Xcode, and click the build button, but it resulted in errors. I don't have any ios development experience and just start learning react native. Can you give any idea to rebuild my react native project?

Comment: Look in the Product menu for Clean and Build.  If you used the Play button (triangle), that will give errors unless you specify a device just to the right - 'Generic iOS Device' is the default and can't be used for running.  You can select a simulator or a USB attached physical device.  Anyway, even if this doesn't solve it, maybe the links to the docs above will be helpful.

Comment: Finally, it works. The final setting that tackles the error is to use NSExceptionDomains, and I rebuild it in Xcode, then it fetches the API successfully. Thank you.